# Take a new line when using $().html in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to put this in a text area with the id registers and though i tried many ways i was unable to get a new line in the text area

```html
    var r0=0,r1=0,r2=0,r3=10;
    $('#run').click(function(){

         ;

         $("#registers").html('Register 3:'+r3+ '<br>' + 'Register 0:'+r0 );
        

    });
```

and this is the out put i get in the text area

```html
Register 3:10<br>Register 0:0
```

Comment: that states how to get a new line in a text area, what i need is to create a jquery function to print the lines with new line characters

Comment: `i am trying to put this in a text area...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. i have added \n instead of 
.

```
 var r0=0,r1=0,r2=0,r3=10;   
$('#run').click(function(){
     ;

     $("#registers").html('Register 3:'+r3+ '\n' + 'Register 0:'+r0 );


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't just this be done:

```
$("textarea").val('Register 3:' + r3 + '\n' + 'Register 0:' + r0);
```

---

`\n` is used to place a new line characters in the strings especially.

Comment: thnaks a lot it works.......

Answer (score 0):

Use html entity of new line `&#10;`

```
$("#registers").html('Register 3:'+r3+ '&#10;' + 'Register 0:'+r0 );
```

or `\n`

```
$("#registers").html('Register 3:'+r3+ '\n' + 'Register 0:'+r0 );
```